# headjs order of parsing

Tags: javascript

I'm looking into headjs (http://www.headjs.com) to speed up loading of javascripts. 
From the documentation it's obviously possibly to control the execution order of scripts, however, parsing order is a different matter and is, afaik, undetermined.

Before going this route I'd like to know if the following would potentially give problems:

load jquery.js and scripts.js in parallel, like:

`head.js("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js","/js/script.js");`

scripts.js has, among other things, some functions that extend jquery, like:

`$.fn.extend({
    myMethod: function(){...}
});`

Would this potentially give a parsing-problem ('$' or 'jquery' undefined) when scripts.js happens to be loaded (and parsed)  before jquery.js or is the definition of '$' only checked on execution of the scripts? (which wouldn't not give problems, since scripts.js is executed after jquery)

I tested things out a bit and regardsless of the order: 
`head.js("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js","/js/script.js");`

and
`head.js("/js/script.js","//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js");`

the extension seems to work when doing:

`head.ready(function() {
  $('#someel').myMethod();
});`

Somehow, I feel glad it works, but at the same time I'm careful to believe it would work each time. After all, when defining 'scripts.js' to be executed before 'jquery.js' I expect '$' to be undefined.

Some light on the matter would be appreciated!

Thanks, 
Geert-Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the `head.js` docs the `ready` method will fire:

> after all scripts have been loaded and
>   the document is scriptable

So your code in `head.ready` should be OK regardless of the inclusion order.

Comment: ok I understand that, but what I meant was that when scripts.js itself is loaded (i.e: somewhere before head.ready() is fired) , it must extend jquery. For that jquery.js must be completely loaded. So for this load-order DOES matter. Or not?

Comment: actually from the docs, even if the scripts are downloaded in parallel, they are evaluated in the order they are included so if `scripts` depends on `jquery` I'd put it last just in case